# Не скачивается вижуал студио

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Всех приветствую
Скачал Visual studio 2019 все работало
после чего мне пришлось удалить прогу и поставить ее заново
сейчас инсталлер закрывается на этом моменте после чего далее ничего не просиходит
очень надеюсь на вашу помощь)
[image: дальше окно закрывается и ничего далее не следует]

Comment: Точно все удалил или что-то осталось? <br>
" программу нужно удалить из панели управления Windows, нужно еще перейти на Диск C > Пользователи > Твое имя пользователя и здесь удалить папку .vscode. В строке пути нужно дописать AppData, далее переходим в папку Roaming и здесь нужно удалить папку Code."<br> Взял недавно с <a href="https://habr.com/ru/post/490754/#delete"> Хабра</a>, помогло, хотел уже винду сносить)

Comment: не помогло к сожалению